# How to download and install the pcapy package with pip?

Tags: python, pypi

I know that in order to install a package I need to execute:

```
sudo pip install package_name
```

But how can I know what is the name of package -  I should give as an argument.
I found in pypi a package I want to install - pcapy:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pcapy/0.10.3

I tried:

```
sudo pip install pcapy
```

It didn't work...
What is the right way to install this package?

Thank you very much!

Comment: avi@avi-desktop:~/Downloads$ sudo pip install pypi
Downloading/unpacking pypi
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pypi
No distributions at all found for pypi
Storing complete log in /home/vit/.pip/pip.log

Comment: `pypi` is not `pcapy`.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: [Error while installing with Python “pip”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724779/error-while-installing-with-python-pip-cannot-fetch-index-base-url-http)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That package isn't in the PyPI. There's a page, but the source code is hosted elsewhere for some reason (this is the first time I've seen it):

Ubuntu has a (probably old) package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pcapy
```

You can also build it from source:

```
$ sudo pip install "http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=attachment&type=tool&page=Pcapy&file=pcapy-0.10.8.tar.gz"
```