# Can't install Django - Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/

Tags: python, django, pip

I am trying to install Django on my windows computer, but I am unable to install it. 
I have been asked to setup the environment, but I am new to this, I have never used Python or Django before, I don't even know what is the use of Django properly. 
So far I have install Python34.  I have setup the environment variables. I have installed pip. When I run

```
C:\Users\username>pip install Django==1.6.5
Downloading/unpacking Django==1.6.5
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement Django==1.6.5
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for Django==1.6.5
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\username\pip\pip.log
```

What's wrong here?
I have gone step by step according to this guide [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/windows/).
What do I need before installing Django?
Do I need to have any server or database before running this command?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Your link says:

    pip install django

have you tried that?

Comment: yeah I have tried that, it gives the same error.

Comment: it's wrote here python works with python 3.3 not sure it works with upper versions : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/install/

Comment: [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/install/#install-python) is says that it works with 3.4

Comment: your on the development version not the stable version (so not the 1.6.5)

Comment: I don't know, I have just installed python3.4, and tried to install Django, So Shall I uninstall and install python3.3 and try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a pip connection problem. If you are using Proxy it should be connected via proxy. First of all check if you have been connected to your proxy server using this command.

```
C:\>netsh winhttp show proxy
```

If is gives this result.

```
Current WinHTTP proxy settings:
    Direct access (no proxy server).
```

Then it means that you haven't been connected to proxy server. Please set the proxy using the commands below.

```
set http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver:proxyport
set https_proxy=https://username:password@proxyserver:proxyport
```

For more info, checkout this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/windows/#common-pitfalls).

Comment: Now I get the same error for installing PIP.
`C:\Python33\Scripts>python get-pip.py
Downloading/unpacking pip
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pip
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\zhg31838\pip\pip.log`

Comment: `C:\Python33\Scripts\get-pip.py run on 05/15/14 10:34:05
Downloading/unpacking pip
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: timed out
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/ when looking for download links for pip
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/: timed out
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download links for pip
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/`

Comment: @user3365207 check this question I think it comes from a connection problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17416938/pip-can-not-install-anything Are you using a virtualenv or something like that else you can try to reinstall pip. Tell me if it works.

Comment: Yes it worked after setting up the proxy configuration like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/windows/#common-pitfalls). Please edit your answer and write about the proxy settings in the answer for people looking for same question in future