# PIP Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement SQLAlchemy

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, ubuntu-12.04, pip, pypi

- Ubuntu 12.04
- Apache 2.2.22

pip has stopped working on my ubuntu server and gives the below error when I try to download anything.

```
$ sudo pip install SQLAlchemy
Downloading/unpacking SQLAlchemy
  Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement SQLAlchemy
No distributions at all found for SQLAlchemy
Storing complete log in /home/user/.pip/pip.log
```

All of the below also do not work

```
$ sudo pip install --upgrade pip 
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

My `/etc/environment` has the below settings which were working previously.

```
http_proxy="http://myproxyhere:portnumberhere/"
HTTP_PROXY="http://myproxyhere:portnumberhere/"
```

My `/home/user/.pip`

```
------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/bin/pip run on Sat Jun  7 20:08:38 2014
Downloading/unpacking SQLAlchemy

  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/SQLAlchemy
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/SQLAlchemy: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
  Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/SQLAlchemy when looking for download links for SQLAlchemy
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
  Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download links for SQLAlchemy
  Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/

  URLs to search for versions for SQLAlchemy:
  * http://pypi.python.org/simple/SQLAlchemy/
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/SQLAlchemy/
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/SQLAlchemy/: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
  Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/SQLAlchemy/ when looking for download links for SQLAlchemy
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement SQLAlchemy

No distributions at all found for SQLAlchemy

Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 126, in main
    self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 223, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 948, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 152, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for SQLAlchemy
```

Has anyone got any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: maybe the last answer of that question can help you.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17416938/pip-can-not-install-anything][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17416938/pip-can-not-install-anything

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to fetch pypi over HTTPS, not HTTP.

For some reason your pip is configured to retrieve from http://pypi.python.org/simple/ rather than https://pypi.python.org/simple/

Comment: Do you know where and how I can change that?

Comment: There's [~/.pypirc](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/packageindex.html?highlight=pypirc#pypirc) or $PIP_INDEX_URL or [pip.conf](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#config-file)

Answer (score 27):

Answer: upgrade pip.

I had version 1.1 installed. With `sudo pip install --upgrade pip` I got version 8.1.2 and the package I wanted installed properly.

Comment: That is the way I finally used to solve the problem!

Comment: I believe that new versions of `pip` recommend not using `sudo`

Comment: i had 3 pip installed... pip, pip2, pip3... pip2 was the latest one after upgrade... don't know why... so know I use pip2...

Comment: don't forget to follow up with a `hash -r` after upgrading pip

Comment: Thx. U saved my day.

Answer (score 9):

### Solution 1: Upgrade `pip`

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip -i https://pypi.python.org/simple
```

then, you can use `pip` as:

```
sudo pip install SQLAlchemy
```

### Solution 2: Specific the index URL with `-i`

```
sudo pip install SQLAlchemy -i https://pypi.python.org/simple
```

Answer (score 8):

You are not using https connections, which had been used since late 2013.

You may use --index options to correct index url.
See http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_wheel.html#index-url

Comment: Ive tried numerous combinations of "pip --index-url https://pypi.python.org/simple/" and "pip --index- https://pypi.python.org/simple/" but keep getting "Usage: pip COMMAND [OPTIONS]" back with nothing else

Comment: The link is broken, please put the relevant information in the answer

Answer (score 6):

You can pass a specific index url with `-i`:

```
sudo pip install SQLAlchemy -i https://pypi.python.org/simple
```

Answer (score 2):

Although it is old question, my solution may help someone.

```
pip install SQLAlchemy --extra-index-url=https://pypi.python.org/simple/
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try pip install in super user. Type su and your password, then try `sudo pip install SQLAlchemy`