# Updating the pip.conf file to use https

Tags: python, pip

I am having trouble configuring my pip.conf file to stipulate that PIP should look for downloads from 
https://pypi.python.org/simple/ rather than http://pypi.python.org/simple/

I have a related question posted [PIP Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101300/pip-could-not-find-any-downloads-that-satisfy-the-requirement-sqlalchemy) where a couple of people diagnosed what was going wrong. However I am having trouble putting in place the solution.

I opend my pip.conf file located at `/home/user/.pip/pip.conf` using the [pip config file documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#config-file) I added the below. There is nothing else in the file.

```
[global]
timeout = 60
find-links = https://pypi.python.org/simple/

[install]
find-links = https://pypi.python.org/simple/
```

After saving an exiting there is no change. I still cannot run commands such as pip install

```
$ sudo pip install SQLAlchemy
Downloading/unpacking SQLAlchemy
  Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement SQLAlchemy
No distributions at all found for SQLAlchemy
Storing complete log in /home/user/.pip/pip.log
```

My setup

- Ubunto 12.04 VM

Comment: What version of pip do you use? I think, that since about a year ago pip by default requires https and rejects using http.

Comment: pip --version returns pip 1.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)

Comment: It is still checking at http://pypi.python.org/simple/. Your changes are not still being used.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use `index-url = https://pypi.python.org/simple/` rather than `find-links` in your config. This will replace the default rather than just adding another option (which is what `find-links` does).

Comment: Worked! My logfile is now saying "Getting page 'https:.....'" Its still not working but this did answer the question I asked.

Answer (score 13):

Use `index-url =` to replace package index.

Use `find-links =` to append entries.

From latest guide: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/

> The new default configuration file is: `$HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf`
>
> Legacy per-user configuration file which is also respected:
>
> > On Unix and macOS the configuration file is: `$HOME/.pip/pip.conf`

Answer (score 1):

## Update from 2011-04-04 version to latest one

pip version 1.0 is fairly old, pypi shows date 2011-04-04. Consider installing latest version.

Since 2011 there were some significant changes (security fixes, support for wheel format...)

I would first remove completely the `pip` installed by `apt-get`, incl. cleaning whatever is in directories around. And then install using `get-pip.py` as described on [pypa](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/).

I know, that it is often recommended following Linux distribution packages, but with pip it is simply not practical.

Comment: Would un-installing and reinstalling PIP have any effect on packages already installed and virtual environments?

Comment: @Deepend Reinstalling pypi shall not affect other packages. I have reinstalled pypi few times on few servers with Ubuntu 12.04 and all was working well without problems. `pip` is a tool for installing, but the presence of `pip` is not needed for the installed packages to run.

Answer (score -1):

I think your changes are not being used.

`pip install --find-links=https://pypi.python.org/simple/ SQLAlchemy` works on my system.

. The log says it is checking https://pypi.python.org/simple.