# How can I avoid this strange "Could not fetch URL" error when doing any pip install

Tags: python, macos, ssl, terminal, pip

Using python 2.7. Was working fine for months but all of a sudden i start getting this weird error when i try and do pip installs outside of or within a virtualenv. If i do something like this:

```
pip install pandas
```

I am told:

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pandas/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pandas
```

This occurs for just about any pip library and it is infuriating. I tried updating my pip and it said it was up to date. I read somewhere i should try and update my virtualenv which I did with:

```
pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

But it gave the same error. So enraging haha.

Comment: Try easy_install pandas

Comment: tried that and it says it can't find anything called pandas

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary fix, you could fetch the appropriate .whl for your system from
[this link](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/0.20.2/) and install it using

`pip install some-package.whl`

Otherwise, you should check [the top anwser from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17416938/pip-cannot-install-anything) which seems to have fixed the problem when having trouble with ssl.